# Remove Style that was placed with appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used `.appendTo` to place style in the head of my document using the jQuery below:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> #sb-container{ visibility: visible !important; display: block !important;} #sb-overlay{ opacity: 0.5 !important; } </style>").appendTo("head");
```

This code was fired at the beginning of a function. At the end of the function I would like to remove the style I placed.

How would I go about doing this using jQuery? Perhaps there's a way to toggle the appended code? It will only ever be placed if it is not there, and it will always be removed if it is.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I'm guessing there's a better way to get this done than inserting a style block and then removing it.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just add and remove a class to/from these elements?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - Basically I want to lock those style attributes as I have specified for the duration of a javascript function. I thought this would be the easiest way, but someone just mentioned that instead perhaps I should just add a class to the element I was to lock, and then remove the style afterwards. That way I can just use `toggle`. What do you think? How would I go about removing the code I appended if I want to stick with the above method?

Comment: Is this also about shadowbox? I'd really just remove these styles from the source or change them in the source. This are pretty basic styles to modify. Also, why are you using shadowbox over the other immense other modal scripts? Im sure there's another, like ThickBox, Facebox, or something thatll make it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your code in a variable as such:

```
var $codePlace = $("<style type='text/css'> #sb-container{ visibility: visible !important; display: block !important;} #sb-overlay{ opacity: 0.5 !important; } </style>");

 // Then use the $.appendTo() function
 $codePlace.appendTo("head");


... Other code to be executed ...


// When you want the code to be removed just use
$codePlace.remove();
```

Comment: Well that's easy. Now I feel like a dolt. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: :) U're welcome. Sometimes the correct way is the simplest. Always remember the liberty offered to you by Javascript in terms of objects and variables and how u can assign objects\functions to variables, and you'll be set to do anything u have in mind. Although as the guys mentioned above, are you sure u want to do this? There might be other (better) ways of solving the problem at hand!

Comment: I'm actually testing another way right now, assigning the style I want to class names, and then using `.toggleClass` to set and unset the class from the elements in question. Does that sound like a cleaner solution to you?

Comment: Of course! Because for one you styles are contained in a class so if u need to amend it you will know exactly where to find it, for two you have better control over what is displayed and when, for three you have better control over the execution of your code.

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing. Although it's not removing the class when it is suppose to. I have a feeling I have to put the second `.toggleClass` in a callback so it is performed once the function is complete. Now I have to figure out how callbacks work.

Comment: callbacks are very easy, here's an example: `function(callbackFnc) { if ($.isFunction(callbackFnc)) { callbackFnc.call(); }; };`

Comment: I think perhaps I should post a new question concerning this. Any chance you could take a look at it when I do?

Comment: I appreciate any help you can provide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382497/set-jquery-code-to-fire-after-function-has-completed :)