# Set jQuery code to fire after function has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function (I've removed code from the middle that is not important to my question):

```
function shadowBoxRefresh(){
    $("#sb-nav-next, #sb-nav-previous").click(function(){
            $('#sb-container').addClass("visibility_stay");
            $('#sb-overlay').addClass("opacity_stay");
            Shadowbox.close();
            Shadowbox.clearCache();
            shadowBoxSetup();
            setTimeout("Shadowbox.open(c)", 400)
            $('#sb-container').removeClass("visibility_stay");
            $('#sb-overlay').removeClass("opacity_stay");
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is, I need this part:

```
$('#sb-container').removeClass("visibility_stay");
$('#sb-overlay').removeClass("opacity_stay");
```

to fire *after* the rest of the function has completed. I'm wondering if a callback would do the job, but I'm not versed well enough in callbacks to know how to implement it.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what rest of the function? its at the end of the function..

Comment: @Daniel A. White - I know! That's what I thought, but the `class` is being removed *before* they should. I suspect it has something to do with the `setTimeout`.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what setTimoeout does. It's not like `sleep` in most languages, it's "In 400 milliseconds, fire Shadowbox.open(c)" and continues on with the rest of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "after the rest of the function" you mean, "after the Shadowbox.open(c)" that happens .4 sec later, then do this:

```
function shadowBoxRefresh(){
    $("#sb-nav-next, #sb-nav-previous").click(function(){
            $('#sb-container').addClass("visibility_stay");
            $('#sb-overlay').addClass("opacity_stay");
            Shadowbox.close();
            Shadowbox.clearCache();
            shadowBoxSetup();
            setTimeout(function () {
                Shadowbox.open(c);
                $('#sb-container').removeClass("visibility_stay");
                $('#sb-overlay').removeClass("opacity_stay");
            }, 400);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been trying to figure out how to put several things in `setTimeout` for quite some time. Alas, this isn't working either. It's hard to explain what's happening without explaining the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming after shadowBoxSetup() is when you want it

```
function shadowBoxSetup( callback ) {
    // Your code...
    callback();
}
```

To use that

```
function shadowBoxRefresh(){
    $("#sb-nav-next, #sb-nav-previous").click(function(){
            $('#sb-container').addClass("visibility_stay");
            $('#sb-overlay').addClass("opacity_stay");
            Shadowbox.close();
            Shadowbox.clearCache();
            shadowBoxSetup(function(){
                $('#sb-container').removeClass("visibility_stay");
                $('#sb-overlay').removeClass("opacity_stay");
            });
            setTimeout("Shadowbox.open(c)", 400);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It *will* be executed after the rest of the function has completed; statements are executed in order.

Are you saying you want it to execute after the timeout? If so, create a function that encapsulates the two calls and the `open()` call.

If not, you might need to be a bit clearer.